# Node.js express app caching / slow page loads (swig template engine)

Tags: node.js, caching, express, swig-template

I'm in the process of moving my apache site (on bluehost) to node.js (on heroku), and am noticing that it runs quite a bit slower. I'm wondering if it's a caching issue or what I could be doing wrong.

Here is the site on heroku: http://ak-web-prod.herokuapp.com/

Here is the site on bluehost: http://ardentkid.com

If you notice, the page flashes white during load sometimes when navigating the site (which is why I think it might be a caching problem). I've set express config for:

```
app.enable('view cache');
```

doesn't seem to change anything. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is my app configuration

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('config', config);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('db', db);
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.engine('.html', cons.swig);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'))
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser())
    app.use(express.bodyParser()) //enables req.body
    app.use(express.methodOverride()) //enables app.put and app.delete (can also just use app.post)
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'topsecret'
        , store: new RedisStore({
              client:db
            , secret:config.db.auth
            })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize()) // use passport session
    app.use(passport.session())
    app.use(app.router) // routes should be at the last
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    console.log('app in development mode');
    app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
    swig.init({root: __dirname + '/views', allowErrors: true, cache: false});
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('stage', function(){
    console.log('app in development mode');
    app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
    swig.init({root: __dirname + '/views', allowErrors: true, cache:true});
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
    app.enable('view cache');
    app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
    swig.init({root: __dirname + '/views', cache:true});
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Comment: as is, difficult to tell. no code, no page info, no database info and not even info about differences between hosts.

Comment: try running to some speed test on your local machine. If you are using the free version of Heroku, it's an extremely slow service.

Comment: Turns out it was my connection to RedisToGo.. It wasn't connecting properly but I didn't think that would slow everything down. Fixing it also fixed the speed issues.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark it was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to my redis database (on RedisToGo) not connecting properly. I didn't think this would affect the page loads, but it definitely did. Now that it's fixed, the app is speedier than ever!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, but I think there might be two things affecting the load time

1. If you are using the free version of Heroku, it could be causing the slowness.
2. The Headers being sent aren't allowing the browser to cache, requiring it to re-download everything. Ex.

`curl -XHEAD -v http://ak-web-prod.herokuapp.com/assets/img/logo.png`

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
< Content-length: 11264
< Content-Type: image/png
< Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2013 03:41:33 GMT
< Etag: "11264-1364696076000"
< Last-Modified: Sun, 31 Mar 2013 02:14:36 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Connection: keep-alive
```

To have your static assets served up with Cache-Control set to something besides zero, take a look at the static middleware - http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html, it allows you to set the max-age. This will affect images, JS, and CSS.

Comment: didn't seem to change much :(

Answer (score 1):

You should add this :

```
swig.setDefaults({
    cache: false,
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: From the Swig source code: ** Disables caching in Swig: swig.setDefaults({ cache: false }); ** I wonder why would disabling template caching improve site performance? Note that by default Swig caches all templates in memory: ** Default: swig.setDefaults({ cache: 'memory' }); **